# C# AddIn Excel : export xls file in text file with separator

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

It's my first AddIn excel and i've a problem for export an excel's file in text file with a separator ("|").
I would like export the excel's file in the same path, with the extension ".txt" and i would like separate the excel's columns by a specific character ("|").

I've created a button on the ribbon :

```
private void exportSave_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        int lastColumns;           
        lastColumns = usedRange.Columns.Count;
        int endCol = lastColumns;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlSheet = Globals.VATTools.Application.ActiveSheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range usedRange = xlSheet.UsedRange;

        // Save file in .txt in the same path
        string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
        xlSheet.SaveAs(path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlTextWindows);
    }
```

I'm not sure of the format "xlTextWindows".

I identify my columns but I don't know how to add a specific character between the columns before exporting it to .txt

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following code:

```
public static void ExportToPipe(RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    string ExportName = @"D:\Pipe.txt";
    Excel.Window window = e.Control.Context;
    Excel.Worksheet sheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)window.Application.ActiveSheet);
    Excel.Range last = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing); 

    int lastUsedRow = last.Row;
    int lastUsedColumn = last.Column;

    string output = "";

    for (int i = 1; i <= lastUsedRow; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= lastUsedColumn; j++)
        {
            if (sheet.Cells[i, j].Value != null)
            {
                output += sheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString();                        
            }
            output += "|";
        }
        output += Environment.NewLine;
     }

     FileStream fs = new FileStream(ExportName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
     StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
     writer.Write(output);
     writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect !!